# Sqlcmd script task to validate source file and target table

Tags: batch-file, sqlcmd

Let me be very specific with what i need. Problem Statement 1: I have got few text files having numerous records which are delimited by pipeline. These files are there in a remote windows server which are the source file for our daily load into a sql server table. I want to write a scripts which will get the filename from the source file path and the number of records in it.–

Next task is to get the counts from sql server table which is ther in an another server(remote) and then validate the counts of table and file. 
Please help.....

Comment: Give an example of `the filename` and `the source file path` that might be got from it please, and `the name of the remote server` and the relevant table name. And tell us what OS you are running.

Comment: Example of file name-Profile_20140223.txt,
Example of remote server-\\SERVERNAME\ftpfiles\Folder_NAme\Filename,
Table Name- staging_profile,
OS-Microsoft Windows XP...

Comment: Please click `edit` and update your question with the details so the formatting is readable and everyone can see the details. Also, where is the example of the path please?

Comment: Example of file name-Profile_20140223.txt, 
Example of filepath-\\CALDBSCD786V\ftpfiles\Folder_NAme\Filename,
Example of server name-CALDBSCD786V(sqlserver2008),
 Table Name- staging_profile, OS-Microsoft Windows XP...